# Encode/decode html tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, nicedit

I have a textarea beautified with nicEdit plugin.

I need to send the code resultant to my php server by an ajax post. What should I do to escape html tags and receive them in my server?

Also, I need to show them in another web page by another ajax call. In order to decode them after receiving from php, what should I do too?

This is a json I have tried:

```
{'title':'srefzgseg','text':'<a href="link_to_page">s</a>drhgrdshgrdghrdgdgrdg<img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg" alt="dgfvsegfseg" align="none">'}
```

my function:

```
function saveData(){
    var title = $("#titulo").val();
    var text = new nicEditors.findEditor('new_area').getContent();
    var jsonNew = "{'title':'"+title+"','text':'"+text+"'}";
    console.log(jsonNew);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./server/saveNewData.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: jsonNew,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
        },
        error:function(xhr, status, message) {console.log(message); alert("Ha ocurrido un error al guardar los datos");}
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to escape them? If you managed to type them in, you will also be able to read them on the other side. PHP won't do anything special to them. The only need to escape tags is if you want to display the HTML source code in an HTML page.

Comment: if I don't include html tag in my text, php server receive that text, in the moment I do, I don't receive anything in my server. Also, json file is not well formatted if I try with jsonlint

Comment: Did you type in the HTML, or was the Text+HTML already pre-filled in the textarea? In the latter case you do need to escape the code when outputting it to the text-area element. If you just typed it in and the AJAX failed, please share more details, like the relevant part of the code and any errors you got from the JavaScript console and the PHP logs.

Comment: I updated my question with my function and a example of json file

Comment: How did you build that JSON? It uses single quotes, which is not valid.

Comment: I tried with double quotes but I had problems with double quotes in html code

Comment: Just don't make a JSON string by yourself. Pass object literal to `data` attribute of `$.ajax` and jQuery will do the job: `$.ajax({ data: { title: title, text: text }, ... })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. Strings in JSON should have double quotes.

If you need double quotes inside the string too, you need to escape them with a backslash.

But rather than writing the solution yourself, let the JSON-serializing be handled by JavaScript, and you won't have this problem:

```
var o = {};
o.title = $("#titulo").val();
o.text = new nicEditors.findEditor('new_area').getContent();
var jsonNew = JSON.stringify(o);
```

Comment: There is no need to stringify JSON, jQuery can handle it automatically.

Comment: This works. I didn't know about stringify method. Thank you! VisioN, without stringify would it work too?

Comment: Yes, if you just pass `o`, jQuery should stringify it behind the screens.